# Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@4510599a

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMCho.jpg)Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file E:\AndroidStudioProjects\AuthenticApp2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@4510599a.). Check logs for more details

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Find and exchange all ' symbols in your strings.xml or somewhere else in your code with \'

Answer (score 0):

Look into the resources in ids.xml file and comment out each id one by one and try to simulate the emulator. I also had this problem but when I removed the EditText id from the resources of ids.xml, then the issue was resolved.